# $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)P(x)\,dx=0$ implies $f=0$

Tags: real-analysis

**STATEMENT**: Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that for any polynomial $P(x)$ we have

$$\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)P(x) \, dx=0$$

Show that $f(x)$ is identically zero.

**QUESTION**: This is an old prelim problem and I'm having trouble showing it. The usual problem restricts to a bounded domain $[a,b]$ from which we can apply stone weirstrass and some manipulation to get the desired result, but reducing to that case doesn't seem possible here, so does anyone have a suggestion on how to proceed? Some hints would be appreciated.

**EDIT**: Note that this is not a duplicate question. [Does $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x)x^n dx = 0$ for $n=0,1,2,\ldots$ imply $f=0$ a.e.?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19499/does-int-mathbb-r-fxxn-dx-0-for-n-0-1-2-ldots-imply-f-0-a-e?noredirect=1&lq=1). The other post does not assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Does [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17047) provide a counterexample (extended by symmetry)? And [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19499/does-int-mathbb-r-fxxn-dx-0-for-n-0-1-2-ldots-imply-f-0-a-e)?

Comment: Just to clarify, you interpret $\int_\mathbb{R}$ as $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{-N}^N$ and not the Lebesgue integral, correct?

Comment: @mathworker21 wouldn't the two definitions coincide since our functions are continuous in this case? But in any case I assumed it was the Lebesgue integral; there was no mention of anything else for the problem.

Comment: @Ideophage Thanks that works. Guess they didn't really check the problems carefully.