# criterion for vanishing.

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can we say about $f$ if $\int_0^1 f(x)p(x)dx=0$ for all polynomials $p$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17026/what-can-we-say-about-f-if-int-01-fxpxdx-0-for-all-polynomials-p)

I want to prove that for $f \in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ s.t $\forall g \in C(\mathbb{T}) \ \int_{\mathbb{T}} fg = 0$ then $\int_{\mathbb{T}} |f| = 0$.

(where $\mathbb{T}$ is the unit circle).

How to show this?

I thought approximating $f$ by some $h$ continuous, i.e $||f-h||_1 \leq \epsilon$, but I don't see how to procceed from here, any hints or full solutions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17026/what-can-we-say-about-f-if-int-01-fxpxdx-0-for-all-polynomials-p.  It follows from the uniqueness of Fourier coefficients.

Comment: Does C(T) represent the continuous functions?

Comment: If F was nonzero on a set of positive measure, couldn't you approximate the indicator function for that set by continuous functions?

Comment: Thanks Jonas, didn't think it was that much easy.

Comment: For a full solution, maybe not so easy; you have to prove that Fourier coefficients are unique!  Fortunately it *is* easy to Google for references on that.

Answer (score 0):

$$|f(x)| = f(x) \cdot \text{sgn} f(x)$$
Consider $h_\epsilon$ - a continuous approximation of $\text{sgn} f$ such that $h(x') \neq \text{sgn} f(x')$ only in $\epsilon$ neighborhoods of points where $f$ changes sign. Then $x_\epsilon = \int_{\mathbb T} fh = 0$ and $\lim \limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow \ 0} x_\epsilon = \int_{\mathbb T} |f| = 0$.

Comment: How do you choose $h_\epsilon$ to make $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0} x_\epsilon=\int_{\mathbb T}|f|$ true?  Unless $f$ is in $L^2$, it doesn't seem apparent.

Comment: My plan is to construct a sequence of functions that converges to $\text{sgn} f$. I now see that my construction is naive (assumes that the set of points where $f$ changes sign is countable), but I still think that such sequence can be constructed and that integration preserves it's limit (the latter is due to continuity of $F(g) = \int fg$, it seems).
You're right, though. My proof is poor.

Answer (score 0):

The link posted by @Jonas has a Fourier-based solution, but my personal inclination is to use Lebesgue differentiation. Namely, suppose $f\ne 0$ in $L^1$ and let $a$ be a Lebesgue point of $f$ with $f(a)>0$ (wlog). There exists $R>0$ such that $\int_{a-r}^{a+r}f(x)\,dx\ge r f(a)$ for all $0<r\le R$. Hence 
$$\int_0^R \int_{a-r}^{a+r}f(x)\,dx\,dr \ge \frac12 R^2 f(a)>0$$
On the other hand, Fubini yields
$$\int_0^R \int_{a-r}^{a+r}f(x)\,dx\,dr = \int_{a-R}^{a+R} \int_{|x-a|}^R f(x)\,dr\,dx = \int_{a-R}^{a+R} (R-|x-a|) f(x)\,dx$$
which is zero by assumption, with $g=(R-|x-a|)^+$. Contradiction.