# How to Show that $W=\{ p(x)\in R[x]: p(0)=0\}$ is a subspace such that $W^\perp=\{0 \}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $p,q, \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ Define a inner product space by 
>   $$\left \langle p(x),g(x) \right \rangle=\int_{0}^{1}p(x)q(x)dx$$
>
> Show that
>   $W=\{ p(x)\in R[x]: p(0)=0\}$ is a subspace such that $W^\perp=\{0 \}$.
>
> I tried the following:
>
> Let $q  \in W^\perp$ so that
>   $\left \langle x,q(x) \right \rangle=0$, $\left \langle x^2,q(x) \right \rangle=0, \cdots ,\left \langle x^n,q(x)\right   \rangle=0$ this proces gives me $n$ system of homogeneous equations and if I prove the determinant of the matrix associate is invertible, then the only solution would be $q=0$.

Is this somewhat correct? Any other hint for a different approach would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/165825/if-int-01-fxxn-dx-0-for-every-n-then-f-0) for an analytic solution.