# The discussion about $\int_a^b P^2(x)f(x)dx=0$

Tags: calculus

$f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a,b]$,and $\int_a^b f(x)dx>0$. If the polynomial $P(x)$ satisfies $\int_a^b P^2(x)f(x)dx=0$. Prove $P(x)=0$.

Comment: @SimingTu How can you define f(x)?

Comment: I don't think you are able to choose $f$.

Comment: @robjohn The problem seems a little weird.Actually,I think the function of P(x) depends on the root of P(x) and f(x).

Comment: Maybe need some real analysis knowledge to solve it.

Comment: @Gingerjin: Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: Your problem is a variation of this one, 

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/nonzero-f-in-c0-1-for-which-int-01-fxxn-dx-0-for-all-n/92937#92937

Comment: @EduardoSiva: Note that this is one particular $f$ and one particular $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, in addition, $f$ is non-negative, here is a hint.

**Hint:** Polynomials that are not identically $0$ can vanish only on a finite set. Consider the open sets
$$
U_k=\left\{x\in(a,b):|P(x)|>\frac1k\right\}\tag{1}
$$
and let
$$
F_k=\int_{U_k}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}
$$
Show that
$$
\int_a^bf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F_1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty(F_{k}-F_{k-1})\tag{3}
$$
and
$$
\int_a^bP^2(x)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x\ge F_1+\sum_{k=2}^\infty(F_{k}-F_{k-1})\frac{1}{k^2}\tag{4}
$$
What conclusions can you draw from $(3)$ and $(4)$?

Answer (score 3):

You need more conditions on $f, P$.

Choose $f(x) = 1$ when $x \in [0,\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}]$, and $f(x)=-2$ when $x \in (\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}, 1]$. Let $P(x) = x$. Then I have $\int_0^1 f(x) dx > 0$, and
$ \int_0^1 P^2(x) f(x) dx = 0$, but clearly $P \neq 0$.

Comment: Ah, I misread the problem. I thought that somewhere, it said that $f$ was positive.

Comment: Yes, I suspect that $f(x)\geq 0$ should be part of the problem statement.

Comment: If $f(x)\geq 0$ I think this result is true.

Comment: It is true under this condition, as @robjohn pointed out earlier.