# A question related to Stone-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Below equation is satisfied.

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x^nf(x)dx=0
$$

If $n$ is integer with $n\geq0$, then we can't guarantee $f(x) = 0$ for all positive $x$.

When $n$ is rational number with $n\geq0$ , do we get same result?

If so, what about $n$ is real number with $n\geq 0$?

Above integral is improper Riemann integral.

I forgot one condition. f(x) is continuous function.

Comment: Why && \int_{0}^{\infty} x^nf(x)dx=0 && does not translated?

Comment: LaTeX is surrounded by $ signs, not & signs.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the omitted quantifiers: I guess you're asking *does $\int x^q f(x)\,dx = 0$ for **all** $q \in \mathbb{Q}_{\geq 0}$ or all $q \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ imply that $f(x) = 0$?* As an aside: the *Stieltjes ghost function* $f(x) = \exp(-x^{1/4})\sin(x^{1/4})$ satisfies $\int_{0}^\infty x^n f(x)\,dx = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. See [Hans Lundmark's answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/17047) for more on this.

Comment: What's the relation with the Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: If interval is finite, it can be solved by Stone-Weierstrass theorem.. so I made title like that. I don't guarantee that it also solved by Stone-Weierstrass theorem.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\int_0^\infty x^n f(x)\,dx$: is it the Lebesgue integral or improper Riemann integral?