# Why does $\int_a^b fg\, dx = 0$ imply that $f = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Assume that f is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ such that for any continuous function g on $[a,b]$ $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = 0$, then how can I show that f(x) = 0 for all $x\in [a,b]$?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128621/how-can-i-show-that-f-must-be-zero-if-int-fg-is-always-zero

Comment: This question is at the moment closed as a duplicate of  [Nonzero $f \in C([0, 1])$ for which $\int_0^1 f(x)x^n dx = 0$ for all $n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/nonzero-f-in-c0-1-for-which-int-01-fxxn-dx-0-for-all-n). While answers to that question answer this one too, I think that this question can be solved in a much easier way. Maybe [How can I show that $f$ must be zero if $\int fg$ is always zero?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128621/how-can-i-show-that-f-must-be-zero-if-int-fg-is-always-zero) would be a better duplicate target.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: What happens if $g(x)=f(x)$? Since $g$ can be any continuous function, beginning with this is okay.

Answer (score 4):

What happens if you take $g=\bar{f}$? In case $f$ is complex-valued. If it is real-valued, this becomes $g=f$, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Write $g = f$. Then $g(x)\cdot f(x)=f(x)^2\geq 0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Deduce the result of 
$$
\int_a^bf(x)^2 \, dx=0.
$$
If exist $x_o\in[a,b]$ such that $f(x_o)>0$ and $f$ continuous then 
$$
\int_a^bf(x)^2 \, dx>0.
$$