# Construct smooth functions which are in $L^1$ and belong to orthogonal complement of non-constant polynomial class

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am trying to construct functions $f\in C^\infty[1;\infty)\cap L^1[1;\infty)$ such that $\int_1^\infty f(t)dt=1$ and $\int_1^\infty t^kf(t)dt=0$ for all $k=1,2,3,\ldots$.

I have no idea, does anyone know how and help to construct those functions?

Comment: An example (shifted by 1) is the [Stiltjes ghost function](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/17047/).