# Assume if Odd moment of $h(x)$ is equal to zero, is $h(x)=0$? - Fourier moment problem, $x\in[0,1]$ - $\int _0^1\:h\left(x\right)\cdot x^{2n+1}dx$

Tags: fourier-analysis, moment-problem

[Showing that $ \int_0^1 x^{2n}f(x) dx = 0 $ implies $f = 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009062/showing-that-int-01-x2nfx-dx-0-implies-f-0?newreg=80a59554aa904c24a9b8b46773498f48)
Hi, tried looking at this link.
I did not understand how to answer regarding odd function, I receive the answer is that it is not correct, The integral is indeed $0$, but only because the integral of multiplication of odd functions is $0$, it does not say that $h(x)$ must be constant 0.

Comment: There is an easy proof using Stone-Wierstarss Theorem, if you are interested.

Comment: @geetha290krm yea, I know I have to use this sentence, the problem is, how? how am I suppose to relate norm to integral?

Comment: and how exactly should I choose my $g(x)$? I can not say I will take $g(x)=x^{2n}$

Comment: Think with Müntz–Szász theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $g(x)=xh(x)$. Then $\int_0^{1} x^{2n}g(x)dx=0$ for $n=0,1,2,\cdots$. Hence, $\int_0^{1}\phi (x)g(x)dx=0$ for any $\phi \in span \{1,x^{2},x^{4},\cdots\}$. By Stone-Wierstrass Theorem  $span \{1,x^{2},x^{4},\cdots\}$ is dense in $C[0,1]$ (w.r.t. the sup norm). It follows now that $\int_0^{1}[g(x)]^{2}dx=0$ and so $g \equiv 0$ and hence, $h\equiv 0$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I can not understand why you are allowed to choose h(x) as you wish? sorry for being a begineer, I can not understand the proof.

Comment: and just a question, I have to prove $h(x) = 0$, not $g(x)=0$, because I see you had g(x) and h(x). so it doesnt mean that $h(x)=0$, the statement is false, am I right?

Comment: You have different notations in the title and the question. I am using the one in the question. My $h$ is not the given funciton, $f$ is the given function. Now $\int hg =0$ for every continuous function $h$, so I can take $h=g$ to get $\int g^{2}=0$.  @Fourier_Asker

Comment: Oh my, sorry, I will change the title, it has to be $2n+1$, sorry!! one moment!! ( as should be odd moment, i accidently wrote even ), I will fix!!

Comment: Okay, if I understand it:------------ f(x) is like h(x) on mine---------- h(x) is a "new function" ------- and g(x) is also a"new function"------, problem is, you are saying $g(x)=0$ and not $f(x)=0$, so it doesnt imply that $f(x)=0$

Comment: @Fourier_Asker Anyway, I have edited my answer so tha you can understand it better.

Comment: Oh I see now, now I understand it, when you said the one in the question, you meant the linked one. Thank you very much!