# On consequences of $\int_{0}^1f(x)x^ndx=0 , \forall n \in \mathbb Z^+\cup\{0\}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functions, definite-integrals, continuity

If $f : [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function and $\int_{0}^1f(x)x^ndx=0 , \forall n \in \mathbb Z^+\cup\{0\}$ then is it true that

i) $\int_{0}^1(f(x))^2dx=0$ ?

ii) $\int_{0}^1f(f(x))dx=0$ ?

Comment: Note that $f$ can be estimated to within any positive bound by finite degree polynomials.

Comment: See here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/nonzero-f-in-c0-1-for-which-int-01-fxxn-dx-0-for-all-n/

Answer (score 1):

We can use Weierstrass approximation theorem see
[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone–Weierstrass_theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem)

To prove $f(x)=0$
Because,$\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx=\int_0^1 \left(f^2(x)-f(x)p(x)\right) dx\le \int_0^1 \left|f(x)-p(x)\right| dx<M\epsilon$.
Where $M$ is the maximum of $f$ in $[0,1]$ and $p(x)$ is a polynomial choose in Weierstrass approximation theorem .