# Showing a certain function vanishes almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Can someone give me a hint on the following problem? I'm not sure what to do...

Suppose $f\in L^1([0,1])$ is such that for all $n=0,1,2,...$ we have

$$\int_0^1 f(x)(\sin x)^n\,dx = 0.$$

Show that $f=0$ almost everywhere

Answer (score 0):

If $f\in L^1(0,1)$, by setting $g(x)=\frac{f(\arcsin x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$, we have $g\in L^1(0,\sin 1)$ and 
$$ \forall n\in\mathbb{N},\qquad \int_{0}^{\sin 1} x^n\,g(x)\,dx = 0.\tag{1} $$
That implies $g\equiv 0$ a.e. on $(0,\sin 1)$, so $f\equiv 0$ a.e. on $(0,1)$.

Comment: I think you should mention why g = 0 a.e., and I think [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/nonzero-f-in-c0-1-for-which-int-01-fxxn-dx-0-for-all-n) answers that.

Comment: The part about g = 0 a.e. just follows from the fact that g (being continuous on closed intervals) is the uniform limit of polynomials, on closed intervals of course, right?

Comment: @SwifferCat $g$ isn't continuous. but, you may approximate $f$ with continuous function in $L_1$ norm.

Comment: @user251257: thanks, I was just saying that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio oh sorry :(

Comment: @user251257: don't be sorry, you saved me from typing that :D

Comment: @user251257 and Jack D'Aurizio.  I thought it might be useful for the OP and other readers to have the reference by name to [The Weierstass Approximation Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem#Weierstrass_approximation_theorem)  used herein.