# question about weierstrass approximation theorem true or false justify

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Is the following assertion true or false?

There exists a nonzero function $f \in C([0,1])$ such that $$\int_0^1f(x)x^ndx=0 (\forall n \in \mathbb N)$$ holds.

(Hint: use the weierstrass approximation theorem)

Comment: What have you attempted yet ?

Comment: The statement in this current form is false, since it states for all n. I think, there should be some restriction on n to make the question interesting at least.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nonzero $f \in C([0, 1])$ for which $\int_0^1 f(x)x^n dx = 0$ for all $n$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/nonzero-f-in-c0-1-for-which-int-01-fxxn-dx-0-for-all-n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From weierstrass approximation theorem, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a polynomial $P_{\epsilon}(x)$ such that
$$\int_0^1 |f(x) - P_{\epsilon}(x)| dx \le \epsilon$$
Now, from the condition of this question,
$$\int_0^1f(x)P_{\epsilon}(x) dx = 0 $$
So, (using fact f is continuous on closed interval)
$$\int_0^1f^2(x)dx = \int_0^1f(x)(f(x) - P_{\epsilon}(x))dx \le \int_0^1|f(x)|\epsilon dx = \epsilon \int_0^1|f(x)dx$$

let $\epsilon \to 0$, we have
$$\int_0^1(f(x))^2dx = 0$$
since f is continuous, so f(x) = 0 for all $0\le x \le 1$

Therefore, there exists no such function to satisfy conditions of the question.

QED