# How do you explain this step in the following integral due to Stieltjes?

Tags: analysis

I am working through John Todd's *Introduction to the Constructive Theory of Functions* (1963). On page 47, he computes the following integral (due to Stieltjes):
\begin{align*}
  \mu_n&=\int_0^\infty x^ne^{-x^{1/4}}\sin(x^{1/4})\;dx\\
   &=4\int_0^\infty e^{-y}y^{4n+3}\sin(y)\;dy\\
   &=4\;\text{Im}\bigg[\int_0^\infty e^{-(1-i)y}y^{4n+3}\;dy \bigg]\\
   &\overset{\mathrm{?}}{=}4\;\text{Im}\bigg[ (1-i)^{-4n-4}\int_0^\infty e^{-y}y^{4n+3}\;dy  \bigg]\\
   &=4\;\text{Im}\bigg[ (-4)^{-n-1}\int_0^\infty e^{-y}y^{4n+3}\;dy  \bigg]\\
   &=0.
 \end{align*}

I understand every equality except the one with the ? over it. Does anyone see how it works?

Comment: Set $t=(1-i)y$ and maybe argue something about deforming the contour in the complex plane since the integrand is analytic? By the way, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/nonzero-f-in-c0-1-for-which-int-01-fxxn-dx-0-for-all-n/17047#17047) is another way of computing this integral.